# checking motor connection

Tags: raspbian

i have recently bought a robotic kit called AlphaBot. 
The thing is the motor doesnt work even with simple code such as:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)

gpio.setup(12, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(21, gpio.OUT)

gpio.output(12, True)
gpio.output(21, True)
time.sleep(1) 

gpio.output(12, False)
gpio.output(21, False)
time.sleep.(1)

gpio.cleanup()
```

is there a way to check if the motors are actually working/connected properly?

Unfortunately there isnt anything on troubleshooting. 
This was the diagram that was included in the manual.

[image]

Comment: What does the manual of the AlphaBot tell you about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Wiring? You're using `gpio.BOARD`... do you understand what that means?

Answer (score 0):

The motor driver boards I have used expect two logic inputs for control.

Setting both logic inputs low switches the motor off.

Setting both logic inputs high switches the motor off.

Setting one high and the other low spins the motor clockwise (and counterclockwise for one low and the other high).

If this isn't the error we need to see clear photos of the connections you have made.